# If the limit of a sequence of algebraic integers is algebraic, does it need to be an algebraic integer?

Tags: number-theory, limits, algebraic-number-theory

Consider a sequence $\{\alpha_n\}$ of algebraic integers and let $\alpha = \lim_{n \to \infty} \alpha_n$, where the limit is taken with respect to the usual absolute value in $\mathbb{C}$, and suppose that $\alpha$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$. **Does it follow that $\alpha$ is actually an algebraic integer?**

I may be wrong, but I think that this is true at least if $\{\alpha_n\}$ generates a finite extension $K$ of $\mathbb{Q}$: since $\mathcal{O}_K$ is a lattice in some $\mathbb{R}^m$ it has no accumulation points, so the limit of a sequence of elements of $\mathcal{O}_K$ must be itself in $\mathcal{O}_K$.

I suspect that the general case should be true, but I have no idea for how to prove it.

Comment: The algebraic integers should form a dense set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elements of ${\bf Z}[\sqrt2]$ are algebraic integers of degree at most $2$, and they are dense in the reals.

Comment: Could you please be so kind to provide a proof (if short enough) or a reference?

Comment: Take $\sqrt{2}-1$, this is a real number between $0$ and $1$.  For $n$ large, $(\sqrt{2}-1)^n<\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon>0$.  Then, the set of all multiples $k(\sqrt{2}-1)^n$ form a set which is within $\epsilon$ of all real numbers.

Comment: Alternatively, show that the set of fractional parts of the numbers $\sqrt2,2\sqrt2,3\sqrt2,\dots$ is dense in $[0,1)$, then you can get close to any real $r$ by adding the appropriate integer to some $k\sqrt2$ with fractional part near that of $r$.